# Formatting D3.js chart for months end

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've asked this question before and got a good [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772110/easiest-way-to-round-date-scale-in-d3-js).

However, under that scenario it does the axis label from the first of the month to the first of the next month. ie.

```
Jan 1---------------------Feb 1
```

I would like

```
Jan 1---------------------Jan 31st
```

Any ideas that are as simple as using `.nice(d3.time.month)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, nothing as simple as that. This simply isn't what D3 is programmed to do. A way of achieving this would be to set the tick values explicitly, but then you would need to compute them yourself.